# QML: aliases to children properties

Tags: qt, properties, alias, qml, qt5

I created dialog and trying to add some aliases to change it title and text:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 0.1

Item {
    signal confirmed;
    signal canceled;

    property alias title: dialog.title
    property alias text: dialog.text

    signal show(variant caller);

    Component {
         id: dialogComponent

         Dialog {
             id: dialog
             title: "Exit Game"
             text: "Are you sure that you want to exit?"

             Button {
                 text: "cancel"
                 onClicked:
                 {
                     canceled();
                     PopupUtils.close(dialog);
                 }
             }

             Button {
                 text: "confirm"
                 color: "orange"
                 onClicked:
                 {
                     confirmed();
                     PopupUtils.close(dialog);
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    onShow:
    {
        PopupUtils.open(dialogComponent, caller)
    }
}
```

But I has problem:

```
qrc:/ConfirmationDialog.qml:8:23: Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "dialog"
```

So, how to create this aliases? Why Item don't see it? What is the best way to change this properties?

Best regards,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `Component` QML element. Simply make the `Dialog` a top-level item in your `.qml` file and treat **that** as a component for dynamic instantiations.

Answer (score 3):

Dialog object won't be available until u have instantiated it, since it's inside a component.

You can refer it's id, if it is not in the component.